# How do I fix wifi connection in xubuntu with RTL8723BE

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently bought a new laptop (HP Stream model: 11-dOOOnd) and initially installed Lubuntu on it as the only operating system. When I connected to the wifi in my house it usually worked at first, but every day it would stop working. Sometimes it would disconnect and refuse to reconnect, while at other times it would still show the icon as if it was connected, but it would not load any pages or download anything.
I googled and saw a few people commenting that lubuntu often comes with network problems, so I cleared the harddisk and did a fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04.2 instead hoping that this might solve the problems...

The current situation is that I can connect to the wifi network without a problem and usually I can use it for a while until suddenly no pages will load and any downloads will stop while the network manager still appears to be connected. When it stops working rebooting the computer or reconnecting to the network does not help, and the connection is almost always gone untill i try again the next day.

There are several laptops, tablets and smartphones in this house that all seem to connect without problems. Two other laptops that run lubuntu both seem to work fine as well as one laptop on windows.

I really love using xubuntu, but with this current problem my new laptop is pretty useless. I have very limited knowledge/skills on code, software or hardware beyond whatś needed for normal use, so i really don't know where to start.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` has the following output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

I would really appreciate any advice that anyone can give.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does not matter what are you using: Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Wireless drivers are same and problems are same, since these distros use same kernels.

To fix problems with your wireless adapter you can install a better driver from Realtek. I packaged it as DKMS and added to ppa.

You need to be connected to internet some alternative way. If this is a problem, I will add an offline manual too.

You can install it this way. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

and reboot.

Wireless should work well.

Comment: As the wifi was still working I installed the driver right away. Too early to tell if the problem will reoccur. Thank you, I really appreciate your quick and clear help, it's a real relief for me if it works!

Comment: The driver should work well. I just made a dkms ppa. You are a first user. I will appreciate if you help to debug, if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I am happy to help if I can. I will report back if there are any more network problems (so far itś worked great).

Comment: When you are sure that you are happy, you can accept the answer by clicking a "bird" at the left.

Comment: Up untill now the connection worked without problems, but a few minutes ago web pages stopped loading again. I rebooted and now my connection works again (this never used to help before). Not sure if this problem will persist, but i thought i should report it.

Comment: Please do not reboot when a page does not load. First try to ping e.g. google.com. It is hard to tell thatthe problem was not at the other side or with your ISP.

Comment: Ok, next time there is a problem i will try to ping google and report here before doing anything else to it. If there are no problems I will try to find the bird and click on it in a day or two.

Comment: My connection has been more stable since i installed the driver, but today for the 3rd time since then pages wont load. I tried "ping google.com" in terminal and got "ping: unknown host google.com" as result. Same for other random sites. I haven't rebooted and i won't for a while. Anything i should check?

Comment: It may happen if you have too many access points around on the same channel. Or some other interference. Try to change channel in router.

Comment: I'm staying in the countryside so there aren't many wifi signals interfering. Only one other signal (from mobile company) on the same channel. Is it still usefull to change the channel? I tried but didn't manage to access the router ("unable to connect" when I enter the default gateway into Firefox adress bar)